# If a prime number P(n) takes the form x mod 3 (where x is either 1 or 2), is the probability that P(n+1) takes the same form = 0.50?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

All prime numbers greater than and equal to 5 take the form 1 mod 3 or 2 mod 3. Furthermore, there are equal numbers of each in the number line, stretching on to infinity.
Given these facts, it would seem reasonable to assume that if P(n) were, say, of the form 1 mod 2, then there would be a 50:50 chance that p(n+1) would also take this form.
An analogy could be, say, tossing a coin. Having tossed a 'head' it is just as likely that the next toss will also be 'heads' as a 'tail'.

An analysis of all primes from 5 to 1.6 Billion ( drawing on work by S Ares and M Castro ), however, reveals that this is far from the case for the first stages of the number line.

I calculate that the number of occasions where consecutive primes both take the form of either 1 mod 3 or 2 mod 3 is 35,447,544
whereas the number of times they differ ( 1 mod 3 followed by 2 mod 3 or visa versa ) is 43,995,257

This is a difference of some 8,547,713 primes or around 10.8% of the total.

a quick count of the 500 primes between 999,999,982,843 and 999,999,997,391 reveals a similar discrepancy:
Same form: ( 1 mod 3 followed by 1 mod 3 or 2 mod 3 followed by 2 mod 3 ) = 219 times
diff form  ( 1 mod 3 followed by 2 mod 3 or 2 mod 3 followed by 1 mod 3)  = 281 times

in this case a difference of  62 or 12.4%

Clearly, if my conjecture is true, the point at which these two totals converge, must be truly astronomical.

Comment: "there are equal numbers of each in the number line" - how many of each *are there*?

Comment: You seem to take it as your assumption that both options are equally likely, and then it becomes your conjecture as well. But prime numbers are not random numbers, so why should this be the case? The question in itself is interesting (which of the two occurs more often), but I cannot see any reason why the answer should be that both are equally likely.

Comment: Certainly seems significant...with $80$ million tosses of a fair coin, the standard deviation of the number of Heads would just be around $4500$ which puts your big sample at around a $1900\sigma $ event.  Though your small sample would just be a $5.6\sigma$ event.

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to remove prime pairs from your sample, though i don't imagine that makes a huge difference.  There are about $500,000$ twin primes less than $10^8$ and of course those are forced to alternate $\pmod 3$.  Similarly, I'd look at the distribution of prime gaps in your sample.  That would be a natural generalization of your question.

Comment: "there are equal numbers of each in the number line, stretching on to infinity." What does this mean and why do you think it is true?  Are there equal number of even numbers and prime numbers stretching to infinity?  " It would seem reasonable to ... a 50:50 chance"   Why? You have an infinite number of people who are either men or women. You chose one and each person chooses the next. Each person has a 90% chance of choosing his/her gender and a 10% chance of switching. Aren't there the same number of men an women in line as it stretches to infinity?

Comment: "Having tossed a 'head' it is just as likely that the next toss will also be 'heads' as a 'tail'.  What if coins could choice the next flip and coins liked to stay the same 90 percent of the time. The probability of a H following a T is only 10% and of a T following a H is only 10% but there are "the same number" of H and T.  Consider Two countries of the same population.  If you are traveling and you meet a person from country A.  Is the probability that t the next person you see being from country B equal. What if you are in country A. Or a country right next to A.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (in the limit) appears to be yes, but in practice (taking numbers up to any finite large number) the answer appears to be no, and in a predictable way. This is the primary idea of [recent work of Robert Lemke Oliver and Kannan Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720). Specifically, they conjecture that there is a secondary term in the asymptotics that explain the biases one can observe in practice.

In their paper they explicitly consider the possibilities mod $3$ in their introduction. For example, among the first million primes, they note that there are approximately $215000$ primes congruent to either $1$ or $2$ mod $3$, and whose next prime is also congruent to $1$ or $2$ mod $3$ (respectively --- and by $21500$ I mean $215000$ each for the $(1, 1)$ pairs and the $(2, 2)$ pairs), while there are about $285000$ (each) for the $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ pairs.

Generically their conjecture is of the shape that prime ensembles containing primes with the same residue class should occur somewhat less often (in secondary order terms). For the rest, I defer to the paper.

---

### Reference

**Unexpected biases in the distribution of consecutive primes**, by
Robert J. Lemke Oliver, Kannan Soundararajan, https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720